# React: how to replicate a specific component class setstate callback example with functional usestate/useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, callback, setstate, use-effect, use-state

I am trying to convert a simple React component with a this.setstate callback to a functional component with useState/useEffect but i cant reproduce same functionality with latter.

I am using an example of a simple alert/notice system to append and remove alerts after a timeout. Sandbox here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/class-and-function-callback-comparison-54tus?file=/src/index.js

relevant code for comparison:

```
const NoticesWithFunctionCallback = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    alerts: [],
    show: false
  });

  const addNotice = (e) => {
    setState({
      alerts: [...state.alerts, ""]
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await timeout(3000);
      console.log("timeout occurred");
      const newAlerts = tail([...state.alerts]);
      setState({
        alerts: newAlerts
      });
    })();
  }, [state.alerts]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>
        Notices using function component with UseState and UseEffect callback
      </h3>
      <Generator addNotice={addNotice} />
      <Container>
        {state.alerts.map((item, index) => (
          <Alert>some alert here</Alert>
        ))}
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

class NoticesWithClassCallback extends React.Component {
  state = {
    alerts: [],
    show: false
  };

  addNotice = (e) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        alerts: [...this.state.alerts, ""]
      },
      async () => {
        await timeout(3000);
        console.log("timeout occurred");
        const newAlerts = tail([...this.state.alerts]);
        this.setState({
          alerts: newAlerts
        });
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h3>Notices using class component and setState callback</h3>
        <Generator addNotice={this.addNotice} />
        <Container>
          {this.state.alerts.map((item, index) => (
            <Alert>some alert here</Alert>
          ))}
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am hoping for suggestions on how to replace the correctly functioning class component setstate callback component with the function component using usestate/useeffect.

Any suggestions most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need in useEffect here. useEffect triggers every time alerts array is changed: by adding items to it as well as removing. It is also triggered right after initialization, so things get messed up. Instead you should modify addNotice function and update state using the previous one like so:

```
const NoticesWithFunctionCallback = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    alerts: [],
    show: false
  });

  const addNotice = (e) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      alerts: [...state.alerts, '']
    });
    (async () => {
      await timeout(3000);
      setState(prevState => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          alerts: [...tail([...prevState.alerts])]
        }
      });
    })()
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>
        Notices using function component with UseState and UseEffect callback
      </h3>
      <p>I want this to replicate the class component but its broken...</p>
      <Generator addNotice={addNotice} />
      <Container>
        {state.alerts.map((item, index) => (
          <Alert key={index}>Alert</Alert>
        ))}
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

There are some steps to go from a class to a functional component :

**Step 1** :

```
class NameOfComponent extends Component
```

becomes

```
function NameOfComponent(props){
```

**Step 2** : remove the `constructor`

**Step 3** : remove the `render()` method, keep the `return`

**Step 4.** add `const` before all methods

**Step 5** : remove `this.state` throughout the component

**Step 6**. remove all references to ‘this’ throughout the component

**Step 7** : Set initial state with `useState()` (and import it from "react")

Example for a number :

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0) // the useState() param is the initial value
```

Example for an object :

```
const [form, setValues] = useState({
 id: 0,
 first: ‘’,
 last: ‘’,
 password: ‘’,
 subscribe: false
})
```

**Step 8** : - change `this.setState()` by the  the setter you defined ( for example setValues, or setCount in Step 7 )

`this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 )}` would become `setCount(count+1)`

**Step 9 :** replace `componentDidMount` with `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
 fetch(‘url’)
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(items => setSomething(items)
 .catch(console.log(err))
}, [])
```

**Step 10 :**  replace componentDidUpdate, or componentWillReceiveProps with useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
     console.log(myPropsToCheck+ " has changed ! ")
    }, [myPropsToCheck])
})
```

Comment: thanks but question does not relate to how to convert class component to functional component as this has already been done, but specifically how to reproduce the setstate callback functionality for this specific example.